# sonar-scanner setup for separate dependency-check-report for multi modules project

Tags: sonarqube, command-line-interface, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, owasp

I've multi module project setup. Since no Jenkins/Maven setup for my project I use CLI to get the dependency report for each module separately and copied them to root project folder named as per the their module

For exampple :

```
D: MyProject
 --module1
    --src
 --module2
    --src

--dependency-check-module1-report
    --dependency-check-report (XML)
    --dependency-check-report (HTML)
--dependency-check-module2-report
    --dependency-check-report (XML)
    --dependency-check-report (HTML)
```

I've explicitly mentioned the module wise report path in `sonar-project.properties` file

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=MyProject
sonar.projectName=MyProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=src
sonar.java.libraries=src

# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=module1,module2

# Properties can obviously be overriden for each module - just prefix them with the module ID
#module1.sonar.projectName=MyProject-module1
#module2.sonar.projectName=MyProject-module2

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.html
module2.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module2.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.html
```

sonar-scanner run fine but skip to pick up the dependency check as It always check ${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.html which is defined in sonarQube dashboard->Configuraiton->Dependency-Check

In Dashboard I can mentioned report file for only one of the module but I need both module reports to be integrated in SonarQube scan result.

Log:

```
12:45:46.752 DEBUG: Sensors : Dependency-Check -> SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> Analyzer for "php.ini" files -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
12:45:46.752 INFO: Sensor Dependency-Check [dependencycheck]
12:45:46.752 INFO: Process Dependency-Check report
12:45:46.752 WARN: Dependency-Check report does not exist. SKIPPING. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath: ${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.xml
12:45:46.752 DEBUG: Analysis aborted due to missing report file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Dependency-Check report does not exist.
        at org.sonar.dependencycheck.parser.XmlReportFile.getInputStream(XmlReportFile.java:82)
        at org.sonar.dependencycheck.DependencyCheckSensor.parseAnalysis(DependencyCheckSensor.java:173)
        at org.sonar.dependencycheck.DependencyCheckSensor.execute(DependencyCheckSensor.java:227)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:177)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:291)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:286)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

12:45:46.784 INFO: Process Dependency-Check report (done) | time=32ms
12:45:46.784 WARN: Dependency-Check report does not exist. SKIPPING. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath: ${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.html
12:45:46.784 INFO: Sensor Dependency-Check [dependencycheck] (done) | time=32ms
12:45:46.784 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
12:45:46.784 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
```

Is there any way to tell sonar-scanner not to check the dependency report path mentioned in sonarQube-Dashboard but check the sonar-project.properties

Also, If at all it's possible, where can I see owasp-dependency report in dashboard ? ( Is this MyProject --> Measures -->OWASP-Dependency-Check ?)

Right now in Dashboard I only see 'MyProject' and it's adding the no. of vulnerabilities,code-smells etc for both module together. I thought I would see module wise scan result separately.

fyi, I an using 
sonarqube-6.7.5
sonar-dependency-check-plugin-1.1.1
sonar-java-plugin-5.7.0.15470
sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227

Thanks in advance for clue.

Answer (score 0):

Properties defined in `sonar-project.properties` file overwrite default values configured on the server.

I've found one issue in the following configuration:

```
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.html
module2.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module2.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.html
```

You forgot to add `sonar` between `module2` and `dependencyCheck`:

```
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.html
```

Maybe this mistake is the reason of the problem.

I hope these files exist on your build server:

```
D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.xml
D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.html
D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.xml
D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.html
```

---

EDIT:

You use Windows, so paths are incorrectly configured. Replace:

```
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module1-report/dependency-check-report.html
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.xml
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:/MyProject/dependency-check-module2-report/dependency-check-report.html
```

with:

```
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:\MyProject\dependency-check-module1-report\dependency-check-report.xml
module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:\MyProject\dependency-check-module1-report\dependency-check-report.html
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=D:\MyProject\dependency-check-module2-report\dependency-check-report.xml
module2.sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=D:\MyProject\dependency-check-module2-report\dependency-check-report.html
```

Comment: Thanks agabrys. It was silly typo. I dont see above exception any more but I see this warning when sonar-scanner try to analysed the dependency report file 

`11:07:07.681 DEBUG: Processing dependency 'module1.jar', filePath: 'D:\MyProject\module1\src\module1.jar'
11:07:07.697 WARN: skipping dependency 'module1.jar' as no inputFile could established.`

I really dont understand what input file it's expecting.

Any clue pleaes If I'm still missing something.

Comment: It means that `module1.sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath` has not been found. Maybe because paths use slashes (Unix) instead of the backslashes (Windows). I've updated the answer.

Comment: sorry for being late. I corrected the missing module name and used backslashes but I see the same error in log. somehow it's referring the Dashboard version dependency report that is "sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath: ${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.xml", instead of reading it from sonar-project.properties file in my project root folder

Comment: If you see `Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath: ${WORKSPACE}/dependency-check-report.xml` then parameters from `sonar-project.properties` have been incorrectly configured. Please add a true content of the `sonar-project.properties` file (without any obfuscation).